# why java allow to assign a Generic type Collection to non generic type Reference in java

Tags: java, generics

In java we cannot assign variable like

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

But we can assign like

```
List l = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The first one I know that if super class reference would have been allowed then
user could be able to add instance of different class have same super type and it would cause issue while accessing element.

But second case i am not able to understand why it is allowed.

Can anybody please explain it.

Comment: `List l` is most likely seen as a `List<?> l` not `List<Object>`. and `List<?> l = new ArrayList<String>()` will compile.

Comment: but it will also cause same issue as it would be in first statement if it would have been allowed right?

Comment: Don't understand what you tried to say...

Comment: I am assuming he means Object is a superclass of String. Why then is java not allowing "<Object>" but allowing "<?>"